# 'MKMapItem' is not convertible to 'CLPlacemark'

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapitem, clplacemark

How can I convert `MKMapItem` to `CLPlacemark` in Swift?

My code gives me a compiler error `'MKMapItem' is not convertible to 'CLPlacemark'`:

```
var mapItems:[MKMapItem] = []
let mi = self.mapItems[indexPath.row];
ann.placemark = mi as CLPlacemark
```

In ObjC I just did `ann.placemark = (CLPlacemark *)mi;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MKMapItem` is not a subclass of `CLPlacemark`. I'm not that familiar with MapKit, so maybe it was indeed possible to directly cast a `MKMapItem` to a `CLPlacemark` without problem.

[`MKMapItem` does have a property called `placemark`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapItem/placemark) with type `MKPlacemark` though. `MKPlacemark` *is* a subclass of `CLPlacemark` and can be used as such.

Comment: My bad, accidentally removed this property. Thanks.